# AppStore, how to check how previous developer answered encryption compliance questions

Tags: app-store

Previous iOS developer has answered encryption compliance questions in AppStoreConnect somehow so it is published I need to add a build to Testflight and I need to answer the questions in the same manner.

Is there a way to see/check how the questions were answered previously?